# Wordpress: fatal error no access on control panel/admin panel

Tags: php, error-handling, ftp, wordpress

During a clean up of my plugins inside of Wordpress i deactivated the: smart archives reloaded plugin.

Next up: a fatal error when i refreshed the page.

```
Fatal error: Class 'SAR_Generator' not found in wp-content/themes/waldorf/functions.php on line 469
```

So i couldn't access the site and also the wp-admin / control panel anymore. 
Before the clean up i downloaded the whole folder for a backup.

- i replaced this folder with the backupped version:  no change
- replaced functions.php / wp-admin & wp-includes:    no change
- checked my wordpress version: 3.5.1 downloaded a fresh wordpress folder and replaced those wp-admin & wp-includes with the ones on the ftp:  no change.

What to do ??????

Comment: It seems there's a problem in your wp theme (waldorf) in functions.php. Using FTP, Uninstall that theme first and use wp default theme. if this doesn't work, uninstall wp plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to provide a quick reply without seeing what the exact lines were in the waldorf theme that you have, however, it seems to be that the theme assumes that the Class 'SAR_Generator' is available by default and doesn't check if this isn't the case.

I suggest logging in via ftp and finding this section of code in your functions.php around line 469 and comment this out and possibly other lines that relate to this.

Comment: elvinD i don't know how i can unistall plugins / theme with my FTP besides just deleting.... i don't know if you mean this.

@Ajay i've tried this but still nothing happens and the timestamp in my FTP is showing the edited version.  this site part is on http://www.rikvandoorn.nl/waldorf

Comment: I've tried this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/phpmyadmin-to-activate-plugins-who-cant-be-activated-in-options-hacktivate

And deleted the comments for the SAR_Generator class in functions.php

Also tried to rename the plugin in the plugins folder

but both with no success the page / blog is still stuck on that fatal error 

@Ajay

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the theme and not the plugin. What is the code on line 469 onwards of functions.php?